# How to monitor eaccelerator

Tags: eaccelerator

I installed eAccelerator. I can see the cache folder. And there are more or less 300MB space under it.

But how do I know that it's caching data and working well?

Any script to monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to verify that eAccelerator is working. If the command line php binary uses the same configuration file as the php-fastcgi version and/or the mod_php version, you can check it by executing:

```
#php -v
```

When eAccelerator is loaded successfully you will see something like:

> Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies  with
>   eAccelerator v0.9.5-beta2, Copyright (c) 2004-2006 eAccelerator, by
>   eAccelerator

If you create a phpinfo() file you can monitor the memory usage, number of cached scripts and number of stored keys.